# A dictionary type with a defined order of keys

Tags: haskell

I would like to use a type that behaves like a simple list of pairs `[(a,b)]` that serves as a dictionary, mapping keys of type `a` to values of type `b`, while maintaining a "user-specified", defined order of keys.  (i.e. just as with ordinary lists - I would like to be able to "append" an item which is then recognized as the "last element".) However I would like random access lookup on keys with better than linear performance, i.e. what `Data.Map` provides.  One option would be to just maintain an ordinary map in addition to a list of keys that defines their order:

```
data OrderedDict a b = OrderedDict (Map a b) [a]
```

and then define `append` operations, etc. that keep the two key collections in sync.  It seems ugly though to maintain two separate collections of the same keys.  Is there a ready-made data type that already combines ordered keys with efficient random-access lookup by key?

Comment: Java's [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) seems to do something similar: thread a list of keys through the map. Python's OrderedDict is simply a list of pairs, so they're no help here.

Comment: What do you mean with "defined order"? Given two keys `a1` and `a2`, is it a priori fixed whether `a1` precedes `a2` or is the precedence determined at runtime?

Comment: @peter I mean 'defined order' in the same sense as with ordinary lists - if I append `a2` after I append `a1`, then `a1` precedes `a2`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `ixset` library - it allows you to maintain sets indexed by multiple columns (by `a` and by `Int` in your case). This is much more maintainable than keeping maps consistent by hand

Comment: Thanks - `ixset` is cool.  I don't think it quite matches the bill in this case because it can allow inconsistent state (multiple entries with the same `Int` field) and it would require a caller performing an `append` operation to explicitly specify the index - something not required by ordinary lists.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I completely misunderstand your question, Data.Map does exactly this, using the key type's `Ord` instance for ordering. As it's a binary tree, the implementation keeps the keys ordered as well.

`Data.Map.keys` gives you the keys of a map in ascending order; as transformations, such as `map`, of a Map are purely functional the order of traversal is irrelevant, and all ways of getting a sequence of keys or key/value pairs out of a Map gives you an ordered list.

Comment: I believe gcbenison is asking for something like `Data.Map` but with the added property of preserving the order in which the keys are inserted.

Comment: If you have a custom key type, you can have it define its own order though. Although that still only works if the order can be procedurally generated.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to preserve some *fixed* order (e.g. insertion time) in addition of having O(log n) lookup/insertions, you could simply use multiple maps and update them simultaneously:

1. `Map a b` for storing the actual data, and
2. `Map Int a` that gives you the i-th key in the order. (If you also need to query the index of a given key you could add a `Map a Int`)